# How to get ARN of ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I try to create an alb by CDK in TypeScript. But when 'cdk deploy' is executed, I encounter an error with the following code. How can I get ARN of the ALB?

```
AlbStack failed: Error [ValidationError]: Template error: resource alb does not support attribute type Arn in Fn::GetAtt
```

```js
constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const target_group = new elbv2.CfnTargetGroup(this, 'targetgroup', {
    ~
    });
    
    const alb = new elbv2.CfnLoadBalancer(this, 'alb', {
    ~
    });

    new elbv2.CfnListener(this, 'alblistener80', {
      defaultActions: xxx,
      loadBalancerArn: cdk.Fn.getAtt(alb.logicalId, 'Arn').toString(), // <----- Here
      port: 80,
      protocol: 'HTTP',
    });
  }
```

Comment: How did it go? There are still issues with getting the ARN?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the CloudFormation [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-return-values), the `Ref` returns Arn, not GetAtt. Thus, if you want to use `cdk.Fn`, you should use CDK's [ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Fn.html#static-reflogicalname):

> The Ref intrinsic function returns the value of the specified parameter or resource.

Thus, you can try:

```
cdk.Fn.ref(alb.logicalId)
```

Comment: It is deployed successfully. Thank you!